# Calculate the maximum number of consecutive elements without repetitions in a vector. c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, binary-search-tree, treemap

Hi guys i've to calculate the longest sequence of numbers without any repetitions and return the size of the sub-segment.

The point is that im missing something at some point but I don't know where.

```
int resolverCaso() {
    int num;
    int cont = 0;
    cin >> num;
    int var;
    TreeMap<int,int> a;
    int aux;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cin >> var;
        if (!a.contains(var)) {
            a[var] = i;
            aux = var;
            cont++;

        }
        else {  
            if (a[aux]==i-1 && var==aux) {
                cont = 1;
                a = TreeMap<int, int>();
                a[var] = i;
            }
            else {
                a.erase(var);
                a[var] = i;
            }

        }
        if (cont > max) {
            max = cont;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I've tried the following cases with this outputs and everything seems to be ok.

```
 E:1 2 3 1 2 3          O:3
 E:2 2 2 2              O:1
 E:4 5 6 7 6            O:4
 E:7 8 9 10 7 8 9 11 2   O:6
 E:7 8 9 10 10 10 1 2 3 4  O:5
 E:3 4 2 3 4 2 8 9 10 11 O:7
 E:0 O:0 ( empty vector ).
 E:1 O:1
```

So basically im looking for some sequence that doesn't work with my code.

Thanks.

Comment: you wrote the code you tested it, all the tests seem to be ok... congratulations, whats next?

Comment: case #2 seems wrong. 2 2 2 2 result should be 1.

Comment: its fine I just wrote it bad sorry.

Comment: tobi303 I know its bad because I must upload it and the site that im uploading it determinates if its fine or not.

Comment: @AndrésOrtiz If you're asking for improvement of working code, you're probably better off asking at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: basically im looking for some sequence that doesn't work with my code.

Comment: You should add your last comment to your question, to make it more clear. (As this is non-working code then you're right here, not on code review)

Comment: E:0, shouldn't O:1? Or is E:0 meant to mean empty input

Comment: @Sean yes I wanted to mean empty input. For every entry I write the size of the vector and then the numbers. If the size of the vector is 0 It would never reach the for and will just return 0.

Comment: @infixed if there are elements , the first element never will be in the vector  because its the first element so it will always reach the  " aux = var;"

Comment: (Yeah, I deleted that comment, but apparently not fast enough.)  But: why is `E:3 4 2 3 4 2 8 9 10 11 O:7`correct? 2,3 and 4 all make repeated entries. The longest sequence then is '8 9 10 11',  so `O` should be 4, not 7, right?

Comment: @infixed the longest sub-segment withouth repetitions is 3 4 2 8 9 10 11 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with

```
        else {
            a.erase(var);
            a[var] = i;
        }
```

You need to do more here. Try the sequence `1 3 4 2 3 4 2 8 9 10 11`.